# PHP stristr() does not work

Tags: php, substring

I have to import a lot of data from one database to another, but I am having some issues that I can not figure out.

Part of the job is to parse the `City` column against an array of cities and find a match if one exists. I tried `stristr()` function, but sometimes this does not work.

For example this is working

```
if(stristr('Murter / ŠIBENIK', 'Šibenik'))
```

but this combination does not work

```
if(stristr('OMIŠ', 'Omiš'))
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php 

May you could switch the params? 
if(stristr('Šibenik', 'Murter / ŠIBENIK'))

-> stristr ( string $haystack , mixed $needle)!

Or try http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-stristr.php

Comment: I have read manual and parameters are in correct order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `mb_stristr`

http://php.net/manual/de/function.mb-stristr.php

The other function can't work with utf-8 symbols

Comment: Thanks, it seems that was issue. Ill accept answer in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 1):

Use a function that can actually work with multibyte strings, such as [`mb_stristr`](http://php.net/mb_stristr).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  if(mb_stristr("OMIš", "Omiš") === FALSE) {
    echo 'Not Found';
  }else{
    echo 'Found';
  }
?>
```

works